# Running QGIS on GPU

Tags: qgis, graphics, gpgpu

I have a QGIS application running on Linux and I added a heavy vector layer.  Every user operation like zooming or panning,  takes almost one minute.  I installed NVIDIA graphics card but it didn't improve the performance at all.  When I run the command `nvidia-smi`,  I notice that my application doesn't appears on the running list.

Is it possible to enforce QGIS to run on the GPU and if yes how can I do it?

Comment: This might be of use: https://github.com/aFuerst/PyCUDA-Raster

Comment: Programs have to be specially written to run on GPUs. This is a specialised task and QGIS isn't done that way. What is a "user operation" in your terminology? That might not even be computable efficiently on a GPU.

Comment: I would recommend to take a step back and allow yourself to think of other solutions than the GPU as well. If this this is of interest for you, share some information about the data source of the vector layer and define "user operations".

Comment: @Spacedman somehow. Yes, they have to be written especially. But QGIS is partially written that way (https://www.itopen.it/opencl-acceleration-now-available-in-qgis/) and yes, probably the question here does not fall into the category that benefits from the previous link.